# get default value from Default Value control in Maximo autoscript

Tags: maximo

In a Maximo 7.6.0 automation script, I can get the default value from the Default Value in Database Configuration with a chain of calls like this:

```py
mbo.getThisMboSet().getMboSetInfo().getMboValueInfo("WONUM").getDefaultValue()
```

If there is a textbox with [inputmode="default"](https://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21417850), I can get that default value with a chain of calls like this:

```py
mbo.getThisMboSet().getDefaultValue("WONUM")
```

If there is also a Default Value control in play, what is the chain of calls to get *that* default value? (The calls above still return the same things.)

Comment: I'm not sure how soon I'll be able to look at the code to check things out, but I believe those Default Value controls are applied to the MBO in the `setAppDefaultValue()` method (https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/155/maximodev/7609/maximocore/businessobjects/psdi/mbo/Mbo.html#setAppDefaultValue()). Looking through there might shed light on how to access the value of one of those controls on a field.

Comment: There are indications that any default value control gets put into the MboSet's defaultValue hash along with other application defaults (maybe overwriting what was there from other sources) when the databean initializes. That 'getDefaultValue("WONUM")' you have there accesses the defaultValue hash and so should return you the results of any default value control affecting it (unless something more "recent" overwrites it, maybe).

Comment: @Dex I will check out `MboSet.getDefaultValueHash()` when I can, but it may not be soon. Thank you for continuing to dig.

Comment: @Dex As stated in the docs, `MboSet.getDefaultValueHash()` returns a Set of `attributeName=valueString` pairs, but there is no indication where the `valueString` comes from. The value from a DefaultValue control is not included in that Set. On a separate note, a control with `inputmode="default"` will override a DefaultValue control.

Comment: It was a while ago now when I looked at that, but I thought the databean init code (or some sub-method of it) was taking what looked like the default value controls and putting them in that hash. I did not run any explicit tests though, so if yours are showing the defaults not being present, then I guess it's not doing what it looked like it was doing.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like there is an easy way to get this data via some helper method like those. The `setAppDefaultValue()` method reads these values in and applies them to the MBO at some point during the load or init of the MBO.

According to the JavaDocs for that method (https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/155/maximodev/7609/maximocore/businessobjects/psdi/mbo/Mbo.html#setAppDefaultValue()), the data is stored in the `appfielddefault` table, if you wanted to pursue that route.

Looking through the code of that method, it fetches a few pieces of information and then uses the data dictionary to get all of that default data (via the following line).

```
/* 7320 */     HashMap defaultAppVal = getMboServer().getMaximoDD().getAppFieldDefaults(appStr.toUpperCase(), getMboSetInfo().getObjectName().toUpperCase(), siteStr, getUserName().toUpperCase(), groupSet);
```

Comment: AppFieldDefaults seems to be different than a Default Value control, given that we have many Default Value controls but no records in AppFieldDefaults. So, `setAppDefaultValue()`/`getAppFieldDefaults()` seems like a fourth way to set / get defaults for an app, but how to get the value from a Default Value control still seems elusive.

Comment: I also see a "setDefaultValues()" method on MBO that is referencing a name of JSPvalues. I haven't looked into it at all yet, and that map seems to come out of nowhere.